# Graphite Render URL API to Splunk - Track received events?

Tags: graphite, splunk, statsd

I'd like to setup a scripted input in Splunk to do a curl against the render url api for Graphite. I imagine I could configure this input to run on the minute, and retrieve that last minutes worth of events.

My concern with this is that some events might be missed, or duplicated.

Has anybody done something similar to this? How could I keep track of the events from Graphite that I have already read?

Answer (score 0):

If you write a modular input you can use data checkpoints. See the docs for more info: http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.1/AdvancedDev/ModInputsCheckpoint

Answer (score 0):

> My concern with this is that some events might be missed, or duplicated.

Yes, it may go missing. In two cases-

1. If you're pushing your graphite server to the limits, there is a lag between the point wherein the datapoint is received and its flushing to disk. With large queues, i have seen this go upto 20 mins. (IO is the constraint here).

   For example- in the case above wherein there's a 20 minute lag, and i am storing data at a 1m granularity- i will have the latest 20 datapoints with `NULL` against the `timestamp`. Of-course, they will soon fill in with the next flush.

   Know that these are indeterminate. So if you have a zero lag deployment- go for this approach.
2. The latest datapoint can or cannot be `NULL` at any given point, because of the flushing nature of graphite, even if nothing is throttling. You can use something like `&from=-21m&to=-1m` to make sure you never encounter this. Note: Your monitoring now lags by a minute. :)

All said, graphite is a great monitoring tool if your requirements aren't realtime.

Comment: ah yeah, very good point. Lag a minute behind, never use "now"